# Problema al cambiar Background de un div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo el siguiente código

```
$(".Div2").click(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
  });
```

El mismo me funciona perfectamente al hacer click me cambia al color amarillo , como podria volver al color original al hacer click o doble click nuevamente.

Alguna sugerencia

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes mirar que `background-color` tiene el `div` y según eso hacer un condicional y dejar el color tal cual estaba, te dejo un ejemplo:

Cabe decir que la propiedad `.css("backgroundColor")` te retornará un string de tipo:

> *rgb(n, n, n)*

```js
$(".Div2").click(function () {
    var currentBackgroundColor = $(this).css("backgroundColor");
    if(currentBackgroundColor == "rgb(255, 255, 0)"){
      $(this).css("background-color","");
    }else {
      $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
    }
    
});
```

```css
.Div2{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Div2">
DIV 2
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias bro excelente , me ayudo mucho tu ayuda

Comment: Un gusto haber sido útil :D !

Answer (score 1):

Podrias crear una clase con el color que necesitas, para luego agregar o quitar la clase de acuerdo al event que ocurra (click, doble click, etc).

Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').click(function() {
if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
  $(this).removeClass('selected');
else 
$(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Hello
</div>
```